# ¿Para que usa una uri android al momento de tener que enviar una intent a un componente?

Tags: android

Estoy estudiando intents en android y tengo este código:

```
Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://hermosaprogramacion.blogspot.com");
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
startActivity(webIntent);
```

Comprendo que lo que hará android es buscar las aplicaciones que tengan componentes que permitan la acción de tipo `ACTION_VIEW` y de esta manera desencadenar la acción.

- ¿Como sabe android que lo que se quiere hacer es abrir una pagina web
  en x aplicación? haciendo uso de la uri?, ¿Como sabe android que es
  lo que quiere decir la uri?, ¿es decir como sabe que hacer con ella?
  cuando se va a comunicar con un componente mediante un intent
- Por ejemplo si hay varias aplicaciones candidatas para hacer la
  acción lo que hace android es mandar un menú de opciones y la app que
  el usuario elija sera la que se designe para recibir el intent,
  entonces en ese proceso ya cuando se eligio el componente y todo ¿Que
  papel juega la uri y como la usa android? y en el caso del ejemplo que puse arriba ¿Como sabe que se quiere abrir una pagina web? ¿Como sabe que es lo que tiene que hacer con esa url?

Answer (score 1):

La constante `ACTION_VIEW` que se define en un `Intent`, indica que mostrará información al usuario y requiere una URI del recurso que mostrará al usuario.

> [ACTION_VIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=es#ACTION_VIEW) Usa esta acción en una `Intent` con `startActivity()`
>   cuando tengas información que la actividad pueda mostrar al usuario,
>   como una página web, una foto para ver en una app de galería o una
>   dirección para ver en una app de mapas, etc.

---

> ¿Como sabe android que lo que se quiere hacer es abrir una pagina web
>   en x aplicación? haciendo uso de la uri?

**Lo define a partir de que usas el protocolo `http://` o `https://`, en base a esto determina que el recurso definido en la URI debe abrirse en un navegador.**

---

> Por ejemplo si hay varias aplicaciones candidatas para hacer la acción
>   lo que hace android es mandar un menú de opciones y la app que el
>   usuario elija sera la que se designe para recibir el intent, entonces
>   en ese proceso ya cuando se eligio el componente y todo ¿Que papel
>   juega la uri y como la usa android? y en el caso del ejemplo que puse
>   arriba ¿Como sabe que se quiere abrir una pagina web? ¿Como sabe que
>   es lo que tiene que hacer con esa url?

Cuando se abre el menú con aplicaciones, indica que solo ese tipo de aplicaciones pueden abrir la URI definida, y no puedes seleccionar otra aplicación que no pueda encargarse del tipo de elemento a abrir.

De otra forma si no se tienen en el dispositivo aplicaciones para abrir el recurso, se obtendría el error:

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent